# unbound method fit() must be called with DecisionTreeClassifier instance as first argument (got Stock instance instead)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to access the `fit` method on the `clf` object in my `Stock` class, I get this error:

`unbound method fit() must be called with DecisionTreeClassifier instance as first argument (got Stock instance instead)`

Stock class:

```
class Stock():
    def __init__(self,equity, history):
        self.equity = equity
        self.history = history
        self.clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier

    # Couldn't use built-in comparable method
    # This method is a workaround.
    def exists(self, allCompanies):
        exists = False;
        for other in allCompanies:
            if self.equity.sid == other.equity.sid:
                exists = True

        return exists
```

Where I'm instantiating the class:

```
....
    arr.append(Stock(equity, history))
```

Where the error is thrown:

```
...
                if current > prev:
                    Stock.clf.fit(Stock, 1)
                else:
                    Stock.clf.fit(Stock, 0)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the other correct answers, here's a little example which will help you to understand what your buggy line `self.clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` means:

```
class f(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

print(isinstance(f, f))
print(isinstance(f(), f))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your `DecisionTreeClassifier`

`self.clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()`

Answer (score 1):

You're not instantiating `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`. Therefore, you're calling the `fit()` method *on the class* and need to tell it what instance you want to use, just as it says.

Presumably you want to instantiate `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`:

```
self.clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```